# D3 force directed graph nodes with nested circles

Tags: d3.js

Within my force directed graph, I wish that each of my nodes have :

- Two circles.
- Both circles must have the same size.
- The circles need to be on the top of each other so that visually we only see one.
- The circle that is beneath is the circle that has the red filling.
- The circle on top is the one that has the url as filling.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
    const node = svg.append("g")
        .attr("stroke", nodeStroke)
        .attr("stroke-opacity", nodeStrokeOpacity)
        .attr("stroke-width", nodeStrokeWidth)

        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(nodes)
        .join("circle")
        .style("fill", "red")
        .attr("r", 30)
        
        node.selectAll("circle")
        .data(nodes)
        .join("circle")
        .style("fill", d => `url(#${d.id})`)
        .attr("r", 30)
        .call(drag(simulation))
```

*EDIT 2*
After trying to apply the suggested solutions to my code, I have managed to create the circles as I wanted. The remaining problem is that my circles all seem to be stacked in the center of my svg as my drag(simulation) is not working for the circles anymore.

Here is a screenshot and a more detailed portion of my code below:

[image]

```
  ForceGraph(
    nodes, // an iterable of node objects (typically [{id}, …])
    links // an iterable of link objects (typically [{src, target}, …])
    ){
    var nodeId = d => d.id // given d in nodes, returns a unique identifier (string)
    const nodeStrength = -450 // -1750
    const linkDistance = 100
    const linkStrokeOpacity = 1 // link stroke opacity
    const linkStrokeWidth = 3 // given d in links, returns a stroke width in pixels
    const linkStrokeLinecap = "round" // link stroke linecap
    const linkStrength =1
    var width = this.$refs.mapFrame.clientWidth // scale to parent container
    var height = this.$refs.mapFrame.clientHeight // scale to parent container
 
    const N = d3.map(nodes, nodeId);
    

    // Replace the input nodes and links with mutable objects for the simulation.
    nodes = nodes.map(n => Object.assign({}, n));
    links = links.map(l => ({
        orig: l,
        //Object.assign({}, l)
        source: l.src,
        target: l.target
    }));
  

    // Construct the forces.
    const forceNode = d3.forceManyBody();
    const forceLink = d3.forceLink(links).id(({index: i}) => N[i]);
    forceNode.strength(nodeStrength);
    forceLink.strength(linkStrength);
    forceLink.distance(linkDistance)



    const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
        .force(link, forceLink)
        .force("charge", forceNode)
        .force("x", d3.forceX())
        .force("y", d3.forceY())
        .on("tick", ticked);



    const svg = d3.create("svg")
    .attr("id", "svgId")
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
        .attr("viewBox", [-width/2,-height/2, width,height])
        .classed("svg-content-responsive", true)


    const defs = svg.append('svg:defs');
  

    defs.selectAll("pattern")
    .data(nodes)
    .join(
      enter => {
        // For every new <pattern>, set the constants and append an <image> tag
         const patterns = enter
          .append("pattern")
          .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "none")
          .attr("viewBox", [0,0, 100,100])
          .attr("width", 1)
          .attr("height", 1);
          
        patterns
          .append("image")
          .attr("width", 80)
          .attr("height", 80)
          .attr("x", 10)
          .attr("y", 10);
        return patterns;
      }
    )
    // For every <pattern>, set it to point to the correct
    // URL and have the correct (company) ID
    .attr("id", d => d.id)
    .select("image")
    .datum(d => {
      return d;
    })
    .attr("xlink:href", d => {
      return d.image
    })
    
 
    
     

    const link = svg.append("g")
        .attr("stroke-opacity", linkStrokeOpacity)
        .attr("stroke-width",  linkStrokeWidth)
        .attr("stroke-linecap", linkStrokeLinecap)
        .selectAll("line")
        .data(links)
        .join("line")
        ;
        link.attr("stroke", "white")
 
     
   
       

    

        

    var node  
 var group = svg
        .selectAll(".circle-group")
        .data(nodes)
        .join(enter => {
          node = enter.append("g")        
            .attr("class", "circle-group");
          node.append("circle")
            .attr("class", "background") // classes aren't necessary here, but they can help with selections/styling
            .style("fill", "red")
            .attr("r", 30);
          node.append("circle")
            .attr("class", "foreground") // classes aren't necessary here, but they can help with selections/styling
            .style("fill", d => `url(#${d.id})`)
            .attr("r", 30)          
         
        }).call(drag(simulation))
        
        


    function ticked() {
        link
        .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
        .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
        .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
        .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);
        node
        .attr("cx", d => d.x)
        .attr("cy", d => d.y);
    }


    function drag(simulation) {    
        function dragstarted(event) {
        if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
        event.subject.fx = event.subject.x;
        event.subject.fy = event.subject.y;
        }
        
        function dragged(event) {
        event.subject.fx = event.x;
        event.subject.fy = event.y;
        }
        
        function dragended(event) {
        if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
        event.subject.fx = null;
        event.subject.fy = null;
        }

        return d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended);
    }



    return Object.assign(svg.node() );
    }//forcegraph
```

Comment: Would using clipPath be a viable option?

Comment: Regarding your second edit, in the enter function you should return `node`, otherwise the new nodes aren't part of the selection that invokes `.call(drag(simulation))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrew Reid alluded to, since you want to add multiple circles to the same node, you probably want to do this with one svg group element per node (`g` elements). From there you can add multiple circles by repeatedly taking the same group selection and appending to it.

#### Without Updates

For instance, here's a simple example that uses prepopulated images, courtesy of the Wikimedia Commons. It works in cases where you set the data only once:

```js
var nodeStroke = 'black';
var nodeStrokeWidth = 5;
var nodeStrokeOpacity = 0.8;
var nodes = [{id: 'image-1' }, {id: 'image-2' }];

const svg = d3.select('svg')
        .attr("stroke", nodeStroke)
        .attr("stroke-opacity", nodeStrokeOpacity)
        .attr("stroke-width", nodeStrokeWidth);     
var group = svg
        .selectAll()
        .data(nodes)
        .join("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", (d,i)=>`translate(${i * 100 + 50},100)`);
var background = group.append("circle")
        .attr("class", "background") // classes aren't necessary here, but they can help with selections/styling
        .style("fill", "red")
        .attr("r", 30)
var foreground = group.append("circle")
        .attr("class", "foreground") // classes aren't necessary here, but they can help with selections/styling
        .style("fill", d => `url(#${d.id})`)
        .attr("r", 30)
// can also start drag simulation here:
// group.call(drag(simulation));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <defs>
    <pattern id="image-1" x="30" y="30" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="60" width="60">
      <image x="-44" y="-30" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Mona_Lisa.jpg/158px-Mona_Lisa.jpg"></image>
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="image-2" x="30" y="30" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="60" width="60">
      <image x="-40" y="-30" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/90/Monet_w1709.jpg/163px-Monet_w1709.jpg"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

#### With updates

When updating data, you want to only add circles to new elements. Here we can move the circle appends to be in the first function argument of `join` (the enter function).

```js
var nodeStroke = 'black';
var nodeStrokeWidth = 5;
var nodeStrokeOpacity = 0.8;

// if using a drag simulation, may need to have only one instance of it:
// var dragSimulation = drag(simulation);

const svg = d3.select('svg')
        .attr("stroke", nodeStroke)
        .attr("stroke-opacity", nodeStrokeOpacity)
        .attr("stroke-width", nodeStrokeWidth);
function updateData(nodes) {
  var group = svg
        .selectAll(".circle-group")
        .data(nodes)
        .join(enter => {
          var newNodes = enter.append("g")        
            .attr("class", "circle-group");
          newNodes.append("circle")
            .attr("class", "background") // classes aren't necessary here, but they can help with selections/styling
            .style("fill", "red")
            .attr("r", 30);
          newNodes.append("circle")
            .attr("class", "foreground") // classes aren't necessary here, but they can help with selections/styling
            .style("fill", d => `url(#${d.id})`)
            .attr("r", 30)
          // if using the drag simulation:
          // newNodes.call(dragSimulation);
          return newNodes;
        })
        .attr("transform", (d,i)=>`translate(${i * 100 + 50},100)`);
}
var data =  [{id: 'image-1' }, {id: 'image-2' }];
updateData(data);
setTimeout(function () {
  data.push({id: 'image-1' });
  updateData(data);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <defs>
    <pattern id="image-1" x="30" y="30" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="60" width="60">
      <image x="-44" y="-30" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Mona_Lisa.jpg/158px-Mona_Lisa.jpg"></image>
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="image-2" x="30" y="30" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="60" width="60">
      <image x="-40" y="-30" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/90/Monet_w1709.jpg/163px-Monet_w1709.jpg"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior:

`node` is a selection of circles - your code block here:

```
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("stroke", nodeStroke)
    .attr("stroke-opacity", nodeStrokeOpacity)
    .attr("stroke-width", nodeStrokeWidth)
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .join("circle")
    .style("fill", "red")
    .attr("r", 30)
```

returns a selection of circles ultimately, which is what `nodes` refers to. The second selectAll statement attempts to append a circles to this selection of circles. A circle SVG element cannot contain a child circle element as this is invalid syntax, so you none of these child circles will render.

If we break that chain up, we can get a selection of a parent `g` to append both sets of circles:

```
 const g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("stroke", nodeStroke)
    .attr("stroke-opacity", nodeStrokeOpacity)
    .attr("stroke-width", nodeStrokeWidth)
```

Then we can use g.selectAll() to ensure we append circles to a legal parent, the `g`. However, if we don't adjust your code a bit, you'll only get one set of circles as the second selectAll() statement will select all the circles added following the first selectAll() statement: The first time you do this you have no circles, all circles are entered/appended. The second time you do this you have circles, one for every item in your data array, so no new circles are appended.

You can apply class names to differentiate in the selectAll statements:

```
 .selectAll(".circleA")
 .data(...)
 .join("circle")
 .attr("class", "circleA")
```

However, if you never intend to add the circles once and leave their data unmodified, you can use `.selectAll("null")`.